# Printing a diamond on a background

Tags: c#, background, console

I'm looking for some guidance, I want to print a diamond on a console window, but I want it to have some columns and rows, I want to be able to move the diamond around by changing some parameters, and change the size of the diamond as well, the display should be like this:

```
0=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=$=====2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1$=$====2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========$===$===2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
1======$=====$==2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
======$=======$=2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
=====$=========$2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
====$===========$=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
===$=============$======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
==$===============$=====3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
=$=================$====3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
2=$===============$=====3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
===$=============$======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
====$===========$=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
=====$=========$2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
======$=======$=2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
=======$=====$==2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========$===$===2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
3=======1$=$====2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=$=====2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
========1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7=======
```

but, the display I'm getting looks like this:

```
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======    $===3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======   $$$==3=======4=======5=======6=======7
1=======1======    $$$==3=======4=======5=======6======7
=======1=======   $$$$$3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======  $$$$$$$=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1======= $$$$$$$3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
2=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
=======1=======2=======3=======4=======5=======6=======7
3
```

I tried this code, but i'm not sure where to go from here

```
namespace Diamonds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            print_diamond print = new print_diamond();
            print_background background = new print_background();
            background.main();
            print.main(5, 15, 5);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class print_diamond{
        public void main(int rows, int x, int y)
        {
            //x = console left, y = console top, rows = the amount of rows to print
            int i, k, count = 1;
            count = rows - 1;

            for (k = 1; k <= rows; k++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }                   
                count--;
                for (i = 1; i <= 2 * k - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("$");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                y++;
            }
            count = 1;
            for (k = 1; k <= rows - 1; k++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                count++;
                for (i = 1; i <= 2 * (rows - k) - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("$");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                y--;
            }
        }
    }
    class print_background
    {
        public void main()
        {
            int i;
            int row = 0, col = 1, rowcount = 1;
            int x = Console.WindowWidth, y = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("=");
                if (i == 7)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    Console.Write(col);
                    col++;
                    y++;
                }
                if (y == 7)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    row++;
                    y = 0;
                    col = 1;
                }
                if (i == x)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (row == 7)
                {
                    Console.Write(rowcount);
                    rowcount++;
                    row = 0;
                }
                if (rowcount == 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the diamond alone

it looks like this then:

```
    $
   $$$
  $$$$$
 $$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$
 $$$$$$$
  $$$$$
   $$$
    $
```

The mess comes in when combining the two, what should I do ?
It doesn't matter if the diamond is filled or not, as long as the diamond is there it will be fine.

Comment: You have too many `Console.Write("=");` and too few  `Console.Write(" ");` in your loop. You have to print `=` reduced by as many times as there are `$`. The opposite goes for ` `.

Comment: Don't print everything in one method. Print line by line. Make a method to print line which combine background and diamond line, where either is a function from line.

Comment: Just a little review - `print_diamond` and `print_background` should be renamed, because they are the dimond and nackground and printing is just a function. and they are not just printing - creating, too. And Calssnames are starting Upper.

Comment: You have a choice, draw the background and then draw the diamond over the top, OR, combine them and display them anything else tends to leave a mess.  If you overlay you must do that, and you wont need to draw the blanks before the diamond, just move x to be ....

Comment: I wouldn't invest to much time in learning the details of the Console I/O. Consider using a big `char[,]` , fill it, set the cursor to TopLeft and then write it all out. Repeat.